# How to iterate list based on first element of list - using struts 2 tags

Tags: java, list, struts2, iterator

I am new to Struts2, I have a list like

```
[1,USER,My Profile,profile.action]
[2,ADMIN,create User,createuser.action]
[2,ADMIN,update User,updateuser.action]
```

So I have to populate it like

```
 -USER
    .MyProfile
  -ADMIN
    .create user
    .update user
```

I am trying like this but not getting as above:

```
<s:if test="#session.rolePermissions != null">
    <s:set var="rowid" value="1"/>    
    <s:iterator value="#session.rolePermissions" var="line">        
        <li>
            <a><s:property value="#line[1]"/></a> <!--  parent -->        
            <ul class="submenu">               
                <li>
                    <a href="<s:property value="#line[3]"/>">
                        <s:property value="#line[2]"/> 
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>        
        </li>
    </s:iterator>    
</s:if>
```

Comment: I seem not to understand your question. What exactly are you trying to achieve. Shed more light to your question

Comment: That list should be shown in UL using struts2 tags [that list is List of individual lists, as shown above] @UchennaNwanyanwu

Answer (score 0):

```
<s:if test="#session.rolePermissions != null">
    <s:set var="rowid" value="1"/>
    <ul>
    <s:iterator value="#session.rolePermissions" var="line" status="ctr">

      <!-- CHECK PREVIOUS VALUE -->
      <s:if test="%{#line[0]!=#previousValue}" >
          <!-- SET PREVIOUS VALUE -->
          <s:set var="previousValue" value="#line[0]" />

            <s:if test="#ctr.index>0"></li></s:if> 
        <li>
            <a><s:property value="#line[1]"/></a> <!--  parent -->
      </s:if>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="<s:property value="#line[3]"/>">
                            <s:property value="#line[2]"/> 
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>        
    </s:iterator>    
        </li>
    </ul>
</s:if>
```

But you should really create an object structure for cases like this.

And finally, for security policy it would be better to use something like Spring Security, instead of reinventing a bugged wheel.